# Simultaneous changing of python numpy array elements

Tags: python, numpy, vector, substitution

I have a vector of integers from range [0,3], for example:

`v = [0,0,1,2,1,3, 0,3,0,2,1,1,0,2,0,3,2,1]`.

I know that I can replace a specific values of elements in the vector by other value using the following

```
v[v == 0] = 5
```

which changes all appearences of `0` in vector v to value `5`.
But I would like to do something a little bit different - I want to change all values of `0` (let's call them `target values`) to `1`, and all values different from `0` to `0`, thus I want to obtain the following:

`v = [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]`

However, I cannot call the substitution code (which I used above) as follows:

```
v[v==0] = 1
v[v!=0] = 0
```

because this obviously leeds to a vector of zeros. 
Is it possible to do the above substitution in a parralel way, to obtain the desired vector? (I want to have a universal technique, which will allow me to use it even if I will change what is my target value). Any suggestions will be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `v` is equal to zero and then convert the boolean array to int, and so if the original value is zero, the boolean is true and converts to 1, otherwise 0:

```
v = np.array([0,0,1,2,1,3, 0,3,0,2,1,1,0,2,0,3,2,1])
(v == 0).astype(int)
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Or use `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(v == 0, 1, 0)
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```